# Hierarchical taxonomy and update_meta_cache function

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy and I recently imported a bunch (15k+) of terms with custom fields (term meta).

Since then admin pages, namely taxonomy add/edit page and CPT (to which this taxonomy is assigned) page became incredibly slow.

I tracked the problem down to update_meta_cache function that fires on these pages on every load. It selects all terms from the database each and every time, here’s a screenshot of Query Monitor output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDfK5.jpg

This doesn’t happen with ‘flat’ (non-hierarchical) taxonomies though. I have another flat taxonomy with 220k+ terms and it's not slowing down anything.
Any idea why does WP update meta cache for all terms on every page load? Is there a neat way to control/disable this behavior?

**UPDATE** I know it's a terrible thing to do, but I went ahead and edited /wp-includes/taxonomy.php - I commented out line 1370 which is:

```
return update_meta_cache( 'term', $term_ids );
```

Now taxonomy page in admin is much faster - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggVTW.jpg

Just to compare - flat taxonomy pages are MUCH faster - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S2AB.jpg - but 2-something seconds time is good enough.

However, CTP page is still awfully slow - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkwGc.jpg - even though DB time is tiny now. Any ideas what gives? Why am I still getting 18 seconds of page generation time? I mean, what does the difference drain into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is a serious performance issue with hierarchical taxonomies. It is known and should be fixed at some point, but this lay down in how WP handle caching.

The problem is not that WP query all the terms (on a flat hierarchical taxonomy as you said, it's a single query) but that it need to do a query for *every* term on a herarchical taxonomy in order to get the term childs. This behaviour is neat in the first case, as WP doesn't need to query on every `get_term` call, but have disastrous consequences in this situation.

There is three possible solutions in this case:

- Use a cache plugin - a correctly configured cache plugin like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) will help to not cache the taxonomy on every page load by having a "permanent" cache. This is not perfect but this is usually the solution I go with.
- Manually disable the caching per `WP_Query` request using the cache arguments:

  ```
  'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
  'update_post_term_cache' => false
  ```

  This will help mostly for front-end queries, so I don't think it's a good solution in your case.
- Do not use a hierarchical taxonomy :)
  No, seriously. If you have that much of terms you should look for an other solution to handle your taxonomy. For example, Woocommerce use a smart trick that bypass this performance issue for the products attributes: all the level-0 terms are taxonomies, which are put together with a special class. This demand some work to set up, but it's a good-solid solution.

I looked for some reference to this performance issue [in the Wordpress core tracker](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/search?q=hierarchical%20taxonomies%20performance&noquickjump=1&changeset=on&ticket=on), but it seems there is no open ticket for this... Maybe you could open one with your data.

Comment: just to confirm - will W3TC help with admin pages?

Comment: Yes if you enable object cache and DB cache it sould improve performance on admin pages as well.